# How to install g++ on FreeBSD?

Tags: gcc, freebsd

On my server with FreeBSD 10.0 I get the following error:

```
# make
/usr/bin/g++ crypto.cpp md4.cpp rsalib1.cpp base64.cpp cmdbase.cpp signer.cpp wmsigner.cpp -o wmsigner
make: exec(/usr/bin/g++) failed (No such file or directory)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /tmp/wmsigner-2.0.3
```

`/usr/bin/g++` doesn't exist, how do I install it/fix this?

Comment: Change the makefile to use `c++` instead of `g++`. Also check any compiler options and avoid g++ specific ones.

Answer (score 7):

`gcc` is still available in FreeBSD, under the ports. To install the latest version (as of this writing, 4.9) as a port, do the following:

`cd /usr/ports/lang/gcc49/ && make install clean`

If you want to install it as a package, do the following:

`pkg install lang/gcc49`

This will install the C, C++, Fortran and Java front ends as `gcc49`, `g++49`,
`gfortran49`, and `gcj49`, respectively.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to install it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @BArtWell The gcc ports always append the version number to the names of the binaries. So g++ 4.7 will be `g++47`, not `g++`. This is done to enable people to have different versions installed at the same time.

Answer (score -5):

It was renamed in FreeBSD 10. Fixed by creating symlink in /usr/bin:

```
g++@ -> /usr/bin/clang++
```

Comment: Since `clang++` does not recognize all the options that `g++` does, and vice versa, this is not a good idea.